# How to use 'Distinct' in vb.net linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using VS 2013, VB, MVC, with Razor views.  I am trying to populate the values of a dropdown list without repeating the same value. I have successfully passed the various building names to the view and populated the drop down list, however I am seeing buildings repeated.

This is what I've tried:

```
        Dim distinctBuildings = From Building In db.tblLocations
                                Select Building
                                Distinct

        Return View(distinctBuildings)
```

What is the proper way to use distinct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building is a row of the table, you need to select a Distinct field (or fields):

```
    Dim distinctBuildings = From Building In db.tblLocations
                            Select Building.BuildingName
                            Distinct
```

Change BuildingName to the name of your field.

Comment: I had some confusion when I initially wrote my question that you've cleared up with this answer.  In my scenario `Building` is a column and I am trying to display distinct values from that column.  Sorry to broaden the question but can this be written to include all rows from `db.tblLocations` where `Building` is the field I am trying to retrieve distinct values from?

Comment: In which case it would be `Building.Building`, so it makes sense to use some other alias than Building for the rows.